# GROK third match

Tags: regex, grok

I'm a grok/logstash newbe and am having trouble matching 3'rd set of numbers in my message.

"message" => "xyz event=345 sequence= 55 value=75"

Basically what I want is the last set of digits '75'

my filter:
grok{ match => ["message", "(?[0-9]+)" ] }
returns 345, how do I specify the 3're match?

Comment: Try `match => ["message", "(?<value>[0-9]+)$" ]`

Answer (score 0):

To match the 3rd set of digits, you need to use

```
^(?:\D*\d+){2}\D*(?<value>\d+)
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gI2rY4/2)

**Pattern  details**:

- `^(?:\D*\d+){2}` - zero or more non-digits followed with 1+ digits, 2 times
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(?<value>\d+)` - the 3rd set of digits

Comment: My message contains unpredicatable charachters at the end so basically I need to grab the 3rd set of digits [0-9]+. basically can't use $

Comment: Ok, then please reword the *the last set of digits* in your question.

Comment: Have you tried the updated solution? If that is not working try `^\D*(?:\d+\D+){2}(?<value>\d+)` that is more restrictive and will require at least 3 digit chunks separated with 1 or more non-digit symbols.